# Flip gameObject when it goes a certain direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am making a 2.5D game where the player can only move up, down, right or left; no X-Axis

I have the controls set-up like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8;
    private Vector3 scale = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
    private Rigidbody rb;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale = scale;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, 2, 5);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float mH = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, mH * speed);

    }
}
```

the problem is that the character should turn when it is heading in the opposite direction,
i could just flip it with the rotation or set the Z scale negative, but that would make it turn istantly, i want to have it turn in the span of a few frames so it doesn't seem unnatural. How can i proceed to implement something like that? Is it even possible in unity?

examples of what [i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb3Nm.jpg)
vs what i would [like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI8dS.jpg):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible in unity?

Most things are possible .. the question is rather always how much effort is needed ;)

---

There are probably many ways to achieve this.

I would simply interpolate smoothly towards the desired forward direction. Something like e.g.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8;
    private Vector3 normalScale = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
    private Vector3 duckedScale = new Vector3(5, 2, 5);
    private Rigidbody rb;

    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    private Vector3 targetForwardDirection;
    private Vector3 currentForwardDirection;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        targetForwardDirection = transform.forward;
        currentForwardDirection = transform.forward;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) ? duckedScale : normalScale;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var mH = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, mH * speed);

        if (!Mathf.Approximately(mH, 0))
        {
            targetForwardDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, mH * speed).normalized;
        }

        currentForwardDirection = Vector3.Slerp(currentForwardDirection, targetForwardDirection, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
        rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.LookRotation(currentForwardDirection));
    }
}
```

[image]